# Recursion algorithm for relatively prime integers

Tags: c, primes

I'm making a function that checks if 2 integers are relatively prime / coprime. The function returns 1 if they are relatively prime and 0 if they are not relatively prime.

The function should be able to accept any integer in any order, given that a and b are both not 0;

To my knowledge having a gcd of -1 is the same as having a gcd of 1. Is that correct?

This is my code:

```
int relatively_prime(int a, int b){

    if (a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
    if (a%b == 0 && (b != 1 || b != -1)) return 0;
    else if (a%b== 0 && (b == 1 || b == -1)) return 1;
    else return relatively_prime(b, a % b);
}
```

Is this correct? Is there any way to simplify or improve my code?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO it would be a lot simpler to make the numbers positive at the start, then you don't have to worry about this (nor worry about what happens with modulus operator and negative numbers)

Comment: `(b != 1 || b != -1)` Can you find a value of `b` for which that's false? Otherwise, if it's always true, there is no reason to add it to the `&&` condition.

Comment: @M.M As OP said " accept any integer", using "simpler to make the numbers positive" is a problem with `INT_MIN`.    Could move to `unsigned` to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    a=abs(a);
    b=abs(b);
    if (b == 0)

        return a;

    return gcd(b, a % b); 

 
}
```

Now if the result is 1 they are coprime . You can convert negative number into positive to see if they are co prime and simplify the code .Technically speaking we can write 0 as 0* any number so 0 will not be co prime with any number other than 1 .

Comment: You can potentially save a recursive call by ensuring that `a` >= `b` before the first recursion.  Just swap the two variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this correct?

No.

`b != 1 || b != -1` is always true.  So code is like

```
int relatively_prime(int a, int b){
  if (a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
  if (a%b == 0 /* && (b != 1 || b != -1) */) return 0;
  // a%b== 0 is never true below after the above line
  // else if (a%b== 0 && (b == 1 || b == -1)) return 1;
  else return relatively_prime(b, a % b);
}
```

...  and does not return 1.

OP's code fails with *undefined behavior* (UB) at least with the case of `relatively_prime(INT_MIN, -1)` as it attempts `INT_MIN % -1`.

---

> Is there any way to simplify ?

```
// Do not call with gcd_recursive(INT_MIN, -1)
static int gcd_recursive(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0) return a;
  return gcd_recursive(b, a % b);
}

int relatively_prime_alt(int a, int b) {
  if (b == -1) b = 1; // Avoid a INT_MIN % -1 in gcd_recursive()
  int gcd = gcd_recursive(a, b);
  return gcd == 1 || gcd == -1;
}
```